# Removed Content-Security-Policy(CSP) header from .htaccess still resources are blocked

Tags: apache, .htaccess, content-security-policy

I am very new to Content-Security-Policy. I added this header in .htaccess file my website to add security but it has broken my website. I tried to white list all the domain with the related resources but that didn't work.

Now I want to completely remove this header from my website. I tried following rule in .htaccess file:

```
Header unset Content-Security-Policy
```

and

```
Header always unset Content-Security-Policy
```

although those header are now not coming in response as I checked in [online server header](http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/) which is

```
Server:openresty
Date:Thu, 25 Jan 2018 09:30:11 GMT
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection:keep-alive
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.38
Vary:Origin
```

but those resource are still blocked by Content-Security-Policy as I checked in firebug console. Also I checked on [Observatory by Mozilla](https://observatory.mozilla.org/) which is saying that my site has implemented Content-Security-Policy.

I now want to remove this header completely and I am using a shared hosting. Please help me with this.